# In $n$ trials there will be an even number of outcomes $6$ is given by $\frac{1}{2}\left [ 1+\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{n} \right ].$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

A fair die is thrown $n$ times. Show that the probability that out of the $n$ trials there will be an even number of outcomes $6$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{2}\left [ 1+\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{n} \right ].$$

I wanted to prove the statement using induction, but when justifying that if the statement holds for $k$, then it holds $k+1$ I get

$$\frac{1}{2}\left [ 1+\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{k+1} \right ],$$

and I don't know how to work with that. I feel like induction might not be the way to go, but in my mind it should since it is a statement $P(n)$ that holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

What would be an appropriate way to proceed?

Comment: Induction does work nicely here. Though it's not always the best approach to prove a statement which is true for all natural numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of an even number of sixes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648601/probability-of-an-even-number-of-sixes) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cleft%20%5B%201%2B%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D%20%5Cright%20)%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cright%20%5D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprobabilty&p=1). There are also others, e.g., [Probability of getting an even number of sixes in $n$ throws of a die](/q/3010793) & [](/q/3010793).

Comment: FYI, the other question I wanted to include is [A die is thrown $n$ times. What is the probability that $6$ appears even number of times?](/q/3618009).